# Longtable in twocolumn mode issues - Springer template (svjour3)

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, sidewaystable

I am using [springer latex](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX_DL_468198_240419.zip) template for an article. Some issues I am facing is about creating a longtable (more than one page) in twocolumn mode.

In particular, since longtable does not work with twocolumn mode, I first change the layout to onecolumn mode (using *\onecolumn*) and then change it back to twocolumn (using *\twocolumn*) once the longtable is finished. And then I create a longtable environment with **longtable** package. However, one problem is that this makes the text separated with the table. I understand this is because the command *\onecolumn* and *\twocolumn* create a new page when they are called. So how to tackle this issue. 
**My code and output are something like follows.**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\usepackage[referable,para,flushleft]{threeparttablex}  %for longtable tablenotes; enable clickable table note
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}    
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-8]

% longtable begin
\onecolumn
%\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth} %set longtable caption length
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
    \centering
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[1]  
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{>{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{2.8cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{1cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{0.9cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}
            >{\flushleft\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm}}
        \caption{Table captions}
        \label{tab:dataset_long}\\
        \toprule
        aaa &bbb    &ccc    &ddddd    &eeeee    &fffffff        &gggg   &hhh    &iii    &jjj    \\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption{(continued)}\\
        \toprule
        aaa &bbb    &ccc    &ddddd    &eeeee    &fffffff        &gggg   &hhh    &iii    &jjj    \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{10}{r}{\footnotesize \textit{Continues on the next page}}\\
        \midrule
        \endfoot
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        12as&dfh 4&&&&op&&&&\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
%   \end{landscape}
%}
\twocolumn
\end{document}
```

[image]

**What I want** is something like what is showed in the following two pictures, which are from Springer journals. Both of them (i.e., longtable with text in the followings or sidewaystable) are OK for me. Could anyone please give me a hint or a solution?

**Longtable from springer articles:**
[image: longtable with texts around it]

**Sidewaystable:**
[image: sideways longtable]

Comment: Did you try the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle)?

Comment: @Bernard Not yet, will have a try, thanks.